# Is the original IV mandatory to decrypt an encrypted message?

Tags: encryption, initialisation-vector

### TL;DR

> If we encrypt a message with an IV, do we need to store this specific IV somewhere to ensure that we're able to decrypt the message later?

There isn't much I know about this. From my understanding, IVs are a way of creating different ciphertext each time the same message is encrypted.

### The Problem

I encrypted a message with a particular random IV, and stored the encrypted message (say,  a file).

Now, I tried decryption with a random IV (different from the one used for encryption), and got gibberish text, instead of the original plain text message which I expected.

But, if I decrypt with the **same** IV as used in encryption, I see my original plain text message.

If this is indeed the case, how is an **encryption key** different from an IV?

#### Implementation Information

I don't think the following has to do with encryption per se, but it's there in case someone needs it:

- I'm using two JavaScript functions, `encrypt()` and `decrypt()`
- Calling those two with the same globally defined IV gets me the original message on decryption.
- Calling those two with different IVs inside them gets me gibberish.
- [Here](https://gist.github.com/roshnet/d352f10ba1020647989653707a6b908b) is the code if someone needs to have a look.
  -I am using AES in CBC mode

Appreciate an answer!

Comment: You need to use the same IV for encryption and decryption. Does this answer your question? [Why does IV not need to be secret in AES CBC encryption?](https://security.stackexchange.com/questions/122274), [When using AES and CBC, is it necessary to keep the IV secret?](https://security.stackexchange.com/questions/17044/), [How to store an AES Key? an Initialization Vector(IV)?](https://security.stackexchange.com/questions/153055/)

Comment: See the [block cipher mode of operation](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Block_cipher_mode_of_operation). IV is used for randomizing the encryption and re-using a key for a long time.

Comment: @SteffenUllrich  I agree, but with AES-CBC, it's possible to decrypt the entire message, except for the first block, without the IV, if you have the key.  See https://crypto.stackexchange.com/questions/1129/can-cbc-ciphertext-be-decrypted-if-the-key-is-known-but-the-iv-not.

Answer (score 2):

For AES-CBC, if you have the key, but not the IV, then you can still decrypt the entire message, except for the first block.  See https://crypto.stackexchange.com/questions/1129/can-cbc-ciphertext-be-decrypted-if-the-key-is-known-but-the-iv-not for more information.

Comment: Its probably worth noting that this answer is specific to the AES-CBC encryption specified by the OP.  In general, there is no guarantee that any given encryption algorithm will treat the IV in the same way.

Comment: @CortAmmon good point.  I've edited my answer to clarify this.